# O tamanho do URL influencia nos rankeamentos de search engines?

Tags: url, seo

Se eu tiver um *link* muito comprido, isso pode ser penalizado pelo Google ou outros sistemas de busca?

Por exemplo:
`www.exemplo.com.br/catalogo/nome-do-produto-descrevendo-mais-do-que-o-necessario-deixando-a-url-muito-extensa`

É pior, na visão de SEO que `www.exemplo.com.br/catalogo/nome-do-produto`?

Comment: https://moz.com/blog/15-seo-best-practices-for-structuring-urls da um aolhada no #6...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Até que alguém prove o contrário ou que mude, já que isto é volátil, não há nada que indique que o tamanho em si afete posicionamento na busca. O conteúdo sim afeta e ser pequeno ou grande  pode ser insuficiente para descrever bem o que é aquilo ou criar confusão com informação demais.

Não posso dizer o mesmo de resultados relacionados ao comportamento dos usuários diante de um URL maior ou menor. Mas de forma geral isto influencia muito circunstancialmente.

Cuidado com conteúdo na internet sobre o assunto, existe muito mais opinião do que fatos.